# Is it possible to start .sh files with git bash minimized?

Tags: git-bash

I wonder if it is possible to start .sh files minimized?
I currently run a setup that closes and reopens a .sh file at a timed interval, this can be somewhat annoying because whenever it starts it comes in front of everything else on the screen.

this is what I am starting:

```
java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar server.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

`git-bash` relies on a single config file `~/.minttyrc` if you're inside there, or look in `%USERPROFILE%` if you're not. If you wanted you could add `Window=min` into that config file, but then it would start your `git-bash` windows minimized as well.

`git` does include a directly accessible copy of `mintty`, on my particular computer its at `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`

Instead of running `git-bash` you could run mintty, mintty can be started with a flag to minimize the window. For example: `mintty -w min`

I would also consider having the restart of the server happen within the shell window.

Comment: Wow. So many answers for "running bash script hidden on windows task scheduler" DO NOT work. This is the first that does!

Answer (score 1):

To extend @kyle-k's answer: the complete hiding of mintty can also be done with: `mintty -w hide` (https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html)

I use it for a Windows Task Scheduler task